# Compiler error when trying to access public const field in C# assembly from C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, interop, c++-cli

I have a C# project that declares the following class :

```
public static class CPConstants
{
    public const double FAR = double.PositiveInfinity;

    ...
}
```

I have a separate C++/CLI project that references the above C# assembly and tries to do this in a method of a class:

```
double farValue = CPConstants::FAR;
```

When I compile this (I'm using MS Build with Visual Studio 2008), I get the following compiler errors:

```
error C2589: ';' : illegal token on right side of '::'
error C2059: syntax error : '::'
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?  How can I access the 'FAR' field from my C++/CLI project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `#define FAR` in the Windows headers for legacy reasons. Try using this line between the header inclusions and your actual code:

```
#undef FAR
```

Comment: This turned out to be the reason.  I think I'll just rename the 'FAR' variable in my C# project instead of doing the '#undef', but this answer is accurate.  Thanks!